# Adding files to a cell phone connected via USB

Tags: usb, file-transfer

My goal is to add files (in particular, a ringtone) to my LG GS170 cell phone. I'm running Ubuntu Linux (and CrunchBang on another machine, but the same problem persists there). When I plug the phone into my machine via USB, I see it when I run `lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 008: ID 1004:6000 LG Electronics, Inc. VX4400/VX6000 Cellphone
```

but it doesn't show up in the `/media` directory as I'd hoped it would. 
Thus my question is:

**How can I add files to my phone when it's connected via USB to my machine?**

Below is what was output when I ran `sudo udevadm monitor` and then plugged in my phone.

```
monitor will print the received events for:
UDEV - the event which udev sends out after rule processing
KERNEL - the kernel uevent

KERNEL[1320439577.540674] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
KERNEL[1320439577.553409] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
KERNEL[1320439577.555385] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1 (usb)
KERNEL[1320439577.558373] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.2 (usb)
UDEV  [1320439577.580299] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1 (usb)
UDEV  [1320439577.621843] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.1 (usb)
UDEV  [1320439577.621894] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.2 (usb)
KERNEL[1320439577.652034] add      /module/cdc_acm (module)
UDEV  [1320439577.652421] add      /module/cdc_acm (module)
KERNEL[1320439577.655490] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
KERNEL[1320439577.655541] add      /bus/usb/drivers/cdc_acm (drivers)
UDEV  [1320439577.655762] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0 (usb)
UDEV  [1320439577.656031] add      /bus/usb/drivers/cdc_acm (drivers)
UDEV  [1320439577.871264] add      /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/tty/ttyACM0 (tty)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are at least three possibilities, depending on how the phone is configured:

1. It might already be visible as some kind of mass storage device. In that case, you might expect it to show up as any other external storage and be mountable under `/media`. But not necessarily (the system might ignore it because of unknown type). To make sure that the device is not already partially recognized, run `sudo udevadm --monitor`, then plug the phone, next hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and paste the text here or on some pastebin-like site.
2. The phone might have two usb *modes* in which it operates. You'd then need to switch the mode (which might default to *modem* or some similar) to *mass storage*. This might be possible either through the phone settings, or done automatically on subsequent connects or forced from the computer-side using a tool like [USB_modeswitch](http://www.draisberghof.de/usb_modeswitch/).
3. Some phones use a separate communications mechanism introduced some time ago by Nokia. On linux, there is a software package called [gnokii](http://www.gnokii.org/) that provides access to such devices. (Look up in your system repositories rather than downloading from the site.)

Comment: I've edited my question to include the result of `sudo udevadm monitor`. I don't know how to interpret it. If you do, please advise.

Comment: This confirms the second scenario - your phone is seen as a modem by default (it is used with `cdc_acm` modem module which triggers creation of `/dev/ttyACM0` modem pseudo-tty).

Comment: ...So try to look in phone documentation or on the web, how to switch it to *mass storage* mode (in phone documentation this might be called very differently!) If that fails, try the suggested tool.

Comment: But I could try USB_modeswitch first, right?

Comment: Sure you can. But it may or may not work. If you have problems, try googling for solutions by other owner of such phone. Use the string *"1004:6000 LG Electronics"* (quoted) in your searches.